# When I Swipe to delete a row, the delete button appears somewhere else on the tableView

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, tableview, constraints

I have a ViewController and added a tableView . It has 2 sections and loads 2 custom cells in each section respectively.But when I swipe to delete some rows in either of the sections, the delete button appears randomly somewhere else on the screen.Tried adjusting constraints of tableView, CommitEditingStyle, canEditRowAtIndexPath.But still the problem persists.[image]

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    if ((indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == 1)
    {
        let complete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Complete".localized, handler: {[weak self](action, indexPath) -> Void in
            if let theSelf = self {
                theSelf.completeTask(indexPath)
            }
            })
        complete.backgroundColor = StyleKit.blue10

        return [complete]
    }
    else if ((indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == 2)
    {
        let reopen = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Reopen".localized, handler: {[weak self](action, indexPath) -> Void in
            if let theSelf = self {
                theSelf.reopenTask(indexPath)
            }
            })
        reopen.backgroundColor = StyleKit.blue10

        return [reopen]
    }
    return []
}
```

Added Sample Code.

Comment: can I ask you how are you implementing the swipe to delet button?

Comment: Which constraints? Show some code, it's impossible to guess what's wrong by just seeing an image.

Comment: after delete a row reload table then check.

Comment: have you set the type of TableView as grouped or plain in storyboard. Try setting grouped in storyboard. if you are doing just programatically.

Comment: There is nothing on the storyboard, everything is done programatically.